# How can I implement a redirect-after-post form with Spring's AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to write a @RequestMapping style form controller that redirects after a validation error and round-trips the values and error messages into the GET requested form (the Spring docs always just show the view being rendered in directly in response to the POST). Essentially, I think this comes down to putting the BindingResult into the session briefly and then placing it back in the model before the form is rendered.

I can't believe that I am the only person that wants to do this, but I can't find a way that doesn't involve duplicating the whole AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter. Am I missing an easy solution?

Comment: I'd like to do this as well. The reason I want to do it is because I am using a form that is http and posts to https (this is because of Google App Engine's SSL limitations) and I don't want the user to ever see the https://foobar.appspot.com domain -- only my actual domain name. What did you end up doing to solve this?

Comment: I haven't solved this. I decided to not worry about the redirect for the time being (even though it pains me).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- put the messages and model in the session
- use [spring webflow](http://www.springsource.org/webflow)'s conversations

(I didn't get the duplication part)

Comment: Because I wouldn't want to "put the messages and model in the session" within every controller, overriding something in the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter or the HandlerMethodInvoker would probably solve the problem, but those two classes don't really lend themselves to being extended.

I know Web Flow has some solutions for this, but it seems overkill for simple forms.